# Finding last post with private field false

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I've been looking, but have been unable to find the solution to my specific issue.

So, if I'm searching for a post like so:

```
@post = Post.last
```

and I need to find the last post where:

```
private = false
```

How would I do that?

I've tried:

```
@post = Post.find_by(private: false, :order => 'id desc')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write

```
@post = Post.where(private: false).last
```